# node: ReferenceError for variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, tvos

I am totally new to Node and so on.

I am trying to redo the application here:

https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs

I have the Apple TV application which run of course on the Apple TV simulator. Then I have a webserver which runs on port 9001.

When I start the Apple TV simulator inside Xcode I get following error

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
```

Error is basically here:

https://github.com/emadalam/appletv-demo/blob/master/web/app/app.js

I am using `var x = require('y')` instead of import

As said, new to JS/Node

Where is my error?

Thanks

Comment: it doesn't recognize require. Is there a reason you aren't using the import syntax?

Comment: No, no reason at all. But also with import is not working. I will give it a try this evening

Comment: This is what I get when I try the following:Unexpected identifier 'ATV'. import call expects exactly one argument.: {
    line = 1;